# How to use getValue() to get date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devexpress

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">From</span>
    </div>
    @(Html.DevExpress().BootstrapDateEdit("dtReturnDateFrom").EditFormat(EditFormat.Custom).DisplayFormatString("dd MMM yyyy").EditFormatString("dd MMM yyyy").UseMaskBehavior(true).AllowNull(false).Value(@DateTime.Today - TimeSpan.FromDays(365)))
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $M.Report.onLoadReport = function (varReportNm, varTemplateNm) {    
    dtTempReturnFrom = $('#dtReturnDateFrom').getValue();
    dtTempReturnTo = $('#dtReturnDateTo').getValue();
    tempReturnFrom = dtTempReturnFrom.getFullYear() + "-" + dtTempReturnFrom.getMonth() + "-" + dtTempReturnFrom.getDay();
    return {        
        /////////// addd this
        format: varTemplateNm,  
        dtReturnDateFrom: tempReturnFrom,   
    };
}
});
```

The error that I get.

I have try find the solution at google but most the solution was not work with my code.

> GetValue is not a function

Comment: There is no such methot in jquery nor in vanilla js. You need `$('#dtReturnDateTo').val()` jquery; `document.querySelector('#dtReturnDateTo').value` (vanilla js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#dtReturnDateFrom')` will be a jquery object & in jequery there is no `getValue()` function .Use `val()` insetad of `getValue();`

If you wish to create a custom function `getValue` you need to extend jquery and create a function `getValue` and define it's body

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  getValue: function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }
});
let k = $('#someId').getValue();
console.log(k)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="someId" value="test Value ">
```

Comment: if l use val(). te result will be 15 nov 2018 instead of like this "Wed Nov 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)"

Comment: You need to pass that value through Date object